# Android 7.1.1 Moto Z Force Bluetooth Won't Turn On

Tags: bluetooth, 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat

I have a Moto Z Force phone on android 7.1.1.

When I tap to turn on bluetooth, it looks like it has been turned on (but doesn't find anything) and if I tap away it shows that it's off.

If I go into advanced settings and hit the "On/Off" slider, it slides over to "On" and then the slider goes dark and becomes non-interactive. The bluetooth is still off and if I go to any other screen (or even shut the screen off on my phone and turn it back on) it goes back to Off.

This happened once before and it seemed to fix itself after an update. Now it's re-broken and no amount of resetting my phone has fixed it. I really don't want to have to do a factory reset.

Comment: Which Moto X (there are at least 4 unique generations and several variants)? Can I assume it is stock and untouched, so it is a Moto X4? If so, have you tried a Network Settings Reset in Settings - Backup & Reset?

Comment: @acejavelin I updated the question - it's a Moto Z Force, actually, and I tried the network setting reset to no avail.

Comment: At this point, your options are pretty limited... If a Network Settings Reset did not help, and you have tried "normal" things like a cache partition wipe, then a factory reset is in order. Even if you call Moto Customer Service, this will be one of the first things they  will recommend. Honestly, if that doesn't fix the issue the device will most likely need to be send in for service. (assuming stock/locked bootloader)

Comment: Question is a bit old, yet I have similar problems with moto E, have you tried to disable "fine location" ? (turn it to GSP only, not GSP+wifi+bluetooth+network).

Comment: @Archemar I tried that after your comment. No changes.